# Combinatorial formulas for k-tuples

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

We have $n$ kinds of objects, and we want to determine the number of ways in which a $k$-tuple of objects can be selected. We consider variants: we may be interested in selecting ordered or unordered $k$-tuples,

\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
    &  \text{Only 1 object of each kind} & \text{arbitrarily many objects of each kind} \\ \hline
    \text{Ordered k-tuples}  & \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} & k^{n}\\ \hline
    \text{Unordered k-tuples} & \binom{n}{k} & \binom{n+k-1}{k} \\ \hline
\end{array}

Have I filled the values in correctly?

Comment: The $k^n$ should be $n^k$, otherwise fine.

Comment: ah, i messed up that one.

Comment: since you can select from n elements for the first position, n elements for the second, and so on, and by the multiplication principle we have such k products.

Comment: For $k=n$, there is only one possible tuple containing no repeated object, so the upper left formula should be wrong.